# MKL multithreading in Ubuntu requiring elevated privileges

Tags: python, linux, multithreading, ubuntu, intel-mkl

I have installed Intel's Python distribution (3.6.3) under Ubuntu (16.04.4). If I run this python as root, the following code shows that my `MKL_NUM_THREADS` environment variable is being respected:

```
import numpy
import ctypes
mkl_rt = ctypes.CDLL('libmkl_rt.so')
mkl_rt.mkl_get_max_threads()  # returns MKL_NUM_THREADS
A = numpy.random.rand(10000, 10000)
A2 = A.dot(A)                 # uses MKL_NUM_THREADS threads
```

However, if I run this python as a normal user, `mkl_get_max_threads` returns 1, and the matrix multiplication only uses one CPU thread.

As a workaround, I tried the following:

```
num_threads = MKL_NUM_THREADS - 1
mkl_rt.mkl_set_num_threads(ctypes.byref(ctypes.c_int(num_threads)))
```

Regardless of whether I was running python as root or not, the `mkl_set_num_threads` call had no effect: `mkl_get_max_threads` still returned the same value as before the call, and the number of CPU cores employed by numpy did not change.

How can I allow Intel MKL to employ `MKL_NUM_THREADS` as a normal user?

Answer (score 2):

We tried the same in virtual box and host machine, we got the following observations:

1. Code executed in Virtual box [image of code executed in virtual box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxCYR.png)
2. Virtual box CPU info   [Image of Virtual box CPU info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pai36.png)
3. Code executed in Host machine  [Image of code executed in Host machine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jw4Se.png)
4. Host machine CPU info [Image of Host machine CPU info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNwn0.png)

For more reference on Recommended settings for calling Intel MKL routines from multi-threaded applications you can refer following link:

https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/recommended-settings-for-calling-intel-mkl-routines-from-multi-threaded-applications